# Access denied for user 'admin'@'MY-IP' (using password: YES) when connecting to MySql RDS in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I am able to connect through the below command and see the databases. But unable to run migration or create tables which results in below error.

**Command**

```
mysql -h endpoint.rds.amazonaws.com -u admin -p
```

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'admin'@'MY-IP' (using password: YES) 
(SQL: select * from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = storydb and table_name = migrations and  
table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

**Queries from MySql command line**

```
show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| storydb            |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+

select user, host, plugin from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user             | host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| admin            | %         | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| rdsadmin         | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
```

**Configuration**

[image]

Comment: fixed it. The issue was password contained #123 so in .env file it was treated as comment

Comment: Yes same issue with # containg password. So change password > in rds instance > modify > new password > save changes > change immediately (yes) > Success.

Comment: For anyone seeing this, keep in mind that AWS RDS server passwords must not contain @, single/double quotes. I was creating the RDS instance through Terraform and the aws provider didn't throw an error about having character '@' in pass phrase. So I had to set a new password for RDS instance

Answer (score 0):

For those using SSL  - RDS (check configuration -> Encryption (enabled)

1. You need to generate a token as the password  (even with auth IAM role)
2. Get the bundle and then try to connect `mysql -h mysqldb.abcd.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com --ssl-ca=global-bundle.pem -P 3306 -u myuser --password=$TOKEN`

More info on how to generate the token and the bundles : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-access-denied/